# Having trouble with showing the forms Of a Qvector Members

Tags: qt

I have A class Named “Student” !
I have a Q Vector From Student class
Now I want To show the form of the 2nd Student in my vector !
but when it shows It is empty , it doesn’t show things the thing in the Ui
What should I do ?! Douse it even can happen ? Or it is not possible in Qt

This is My QVector:

```
StHead = new QVector <Student> ;
```

This is My Code :

```
void MainWindow::StudentSignIn (QString User,QString Pass)
{
///////Sign in things !
    int index = StudentSearch(User);
    Student* at = StHead->data();
    if (at[index].GetPass() == Pass)
        emit Hide_StuLog();
    at[index].show();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't manage your students by QVector<Student>*, but QVector<Student*>. at[index] would become stHead[index]. Otherwise this needs more context.

Comment: But This isn't my problme

Comment: Then add more context (code of Student, code filling StHead). The only thing I can read from the code snippet is that you try to manage widgets by value, which is prone to fail.